# Matcher error: received value must not be null nor undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, assertion, playwright

I am using expect in typescript to write an assertion while writing a Then step definition using typescript in in playwright
I have assigned an the class on this url https://www.gov.uk/help/accessibility-statement to confirm I can see accessibility statement when I land on the page.

I then get an undefined error when I run my tests.

Code written:-

```
import expect from "expect";

Then("I expect to be on the accessibility page", async function(
    
this: OurWorld
) 

{   

    const {page} = this;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
    const headMessage =await page?.$(".gem-c-title__text.govuk-heading-xl")
    console.log(headMessage)
    expect (headMessage).toContainEqual(("Accessibility statement")
        
    );
});
```

I would like to check that the accessibility icon on the accessibility page contains the text accessibility.

The error I am getting back is this:-

```
× Then I expect to be on the accessibility page # step-definitions\feature.step-definitions.ts:28
       Error: expect(received).toContainEqual(expected) // deep equality

       Matcher error: received value must not be null nor undefined
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: How about using `await page?.$(".gem-c-title__text.govuk-heading-xl")` ? Note the dots in between the two class names.

Comment: @Kali that is what I used in the question? Correct me if I’m wrong please.

Comment: well you're not using a second dot. `gem-c-title__text` and  `govuk-heading-xl` are two different classes for that particular HTML element. I've just tried it myself, at least I'm getting a timeout error. Try again with my first comment.

Comment: @kali I see what you mean. I have updated the code in the question. On my machine it has both dots. So if I do a “console.log(head message)” do you get undefined or accessibility statement? I am getting undefined.

Comment: oh, I was just checking it with Java, just tried it now in TypeScript. A few points that I was apparently missing: your `const headMessage` is an `ElementHandler`, testing it with `expect` should give you another error:  
`Expected value:  "Accessibility statement"
Received object: {"_guid": "handle@54089b448011b009d5d631b8799a7ae5", "_type": "ElementHandle"}`

Comment: It is recommended to use a `Locator` instead, like so: `await page.locator('.gem-c-title__text.govuk-heading-xl')`, then check its TEXTCONTENT with `await expect(headMessage).toContainText('Accessibility statement');` Here I'm using `import expect from '@playwright/test'`. Nevertheless, everything else works just fine, I'm not getting any error.